# convert whiteboard cleaner script to php

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to convert this Imagemagick [whiteboard cleaning script](https://gist.github.com/zaa/9949351) to pure PHP using the imagick extension to avoid having to resort to spawning processes with `exec` or the like.

Original bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
convert $1 -morphology Convolve DoG:15,100,0 -negate -normalize -blur 0x1 -channel RBG -level 60%,91%,0.1 $2
```

I'm struggling with the initial Convolve morphology kernel matrix, everything else seems to work I think:

```
<?php

$channel = null;

$convolveKernel = array(15, 100, 0);
$negateGreys = false;

$blurRadius = 0;
$blurSigma = 1;

$levelBlack = 60; // 60%
$levelGamma = 0.1;
$levelWhite = 91; // 91%

$image = new Imagick($file);

try {
    $image->convolveImage($convolveKernel, $channel);
    $image->negateImage($negateGreys, $channel);
    $image->normalizeImage($channel);
    $image->blurImage($blurRadius, $blurSigma, $channel);
    $image->levelImage($levelBlack, $levelGamma, $levelWhite, $channel);

    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    echo $image;
} catch (ImagickException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I'm getting an exception `"The kernel must contain a square number of elements"` but I'm also wondering about the scale of the black and white level values — are these 0-100, 0-255 or 0-65535?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PECL Imagick extension [doesn't implement](https://github.com/mkoppanen/imagick/search?q=MagickMorphologyImage) (or use) MagickWand's [`MagickMorphologyImage`](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/magick-image.php#MagickMorphologyImage), which is the interface for the `-morphology Convolve DoG:15,100,0` flag in the original command.

To use `convolveImage`, you'll [likely need to use an odd-numbered matrix](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#convolve):

> The kernel is a matrix specified as a comma-separated list of integers (with no spaces), ordered left-to right, starting with the top row. Presently, only odd-dimensioned kernels are supported, and therefore the number of entries in the specified kernel must be 3<sup>2</sup>=9, 5<sup>2</sup>=25, 7<sup>2</sup>=49, etc.

But I don't think you'll be able to recreate it as such (at least not as high-quality as the original), since the original flag uses the computed convolution [Difference of Gaussians](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/convolve/#dog) (`DoG`), which you won't be able to recreate using the simpler, more primitive convolve.